# knockout nested model observableArray is not defined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a pretty basic structure, with 2 nested models

```
model1
----observableArray of model2

model2
----observableArray of model3
```

i am able to bind to model1, and iterate over model2 array (using a foreach) and bind to the properties.

the problem is when i try to bind to model3 array:

```
[root] data-bind(blah: model1.property1 // OK
[root] foreach: model2Array             // OK 
    data-bind(blah: model2.property1)   // OK
    data-bind(blah: model2.model3Array) // Undefined exception
```

model1, model2, model3 are all defined the same way

```
var model3 = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data) ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        else ko.mapping.fromJS(_model2Template, {}, self);
}
var model2 = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data) ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        else ko.mapping.fromJS(_model2Template, {}, self);

        self.model3Array = ko.observableArray();
        self.addModel3 = function(m3) {
            if (m3) self.model3Array.push(m3)
            else self.model3Array.push(new model3);
        }
}
var model1 = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        if (data) ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
        else ko.mapping.fromJS(_model1Template, {}, self);

        self.model2Array = ko.observableArray();
        self.addModel2 = function(m2) {
            if (m2) self.model2Array.push(m2)
            else self.model2Array.push(new model2);
        }
}

window.model1 = new model1();
ko.applyBindings(model1);
```

interesting part is that the observableArray on model1 works as expected.. the thing breaks down when i try to access an array on one of the objects in root array!

UPDATE

added the functions used to add new objects in the array

I am **guessing** i need to provide a mapping with create events for each array, but not sure where that would go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out.. the problem was in my add handler

```
    self.addModel3 = function(m3) {
        if (m3) self.model3Array.push(m3)
        else self.model3Array.push(new model3);
    }
```

thought i was clever and assumed that it would be called with no parameters unless i explicitly specified them,

but declaring a click handler this way:

```
<button ... data-bind="click: addModel2">
```

WILL in fact pass the model as first parameter. so i was actually adding root model instead of the nested model i expected. and there were no javascript errors, just the property i expected to be on there was missing in the end

Answer (score 0):

From your example, `model2.model3array` should  be `model2.model3Array`?

Hth,
Aaron

Comment: corrected. this is just an example i made for the question.. all the spellings in my code are correct. it's just for some reason the arrays don't get defined on each create..

Comment: Could you put together a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue? Hard to tell just looking at your code.